# Dockerfile, sbt-assembly - is it possible to use sbt-assembly in dockerfile?

Tags: docker, sbt, dockerfile, sbt-assembly

I have a `Dockerfile` script:

```
FROM hseeberger/scala-sbt:8u222_1.3.4_2.13.1
RUN sbt assembly
```

But when I ran it, I got an error:

```
[error] Not a valid command: assembly
[error] Not a valid project ID: assembly
[error] Expected ':'
[error] Not a valid key: assembly
[error] assembly
[error]
```

I have `sbt-assembly` plugin in my `assembly.sbt` file. 
Is it possible to build project with `sbt assembly` via docker? In normal way it works fine, when I use `sbt assembly`, the problem is with docker.

Other commands like `sbt package` works fine also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem by copying files to repository and set `WORKDIR`. Now I can use `sbt assembly`:

```
FROM hseeberger/scala-sbt:graalvm-ce-19.3.0-java11_1.3.7_2.13.1 as build
COPY . /my-project
WORKDIR /my-project
RUN sbt assembly
```